# What purpose does the "safety" tag serve?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [safety](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) tag has currently 32 questions, ranging from [How unhealthy are aluminum cooking pans?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5798/how-unhealthy-are-aluminum-cooking-pans) to [Fighting fire with electricity. Plausible?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/fighting-fire-with-electricity-plausible).

Those questions span a variety of subjects, on first glance the tag doesn't seem at all useful to me.

Should we eliminate the tag altogether, or is there some way to make it somehow useful?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a tag that doesn't really describe anything. I think it should die.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at the questions and for the majority it did seem to make sense. It needs to be qualified with other things and used judiciously or it will fall into disrepute. I think the trick is to use it alongside some domain tag (like medicine or cooking or bicycles) so we can identify where the discussion is about whether, for example, some drug is *safe* rather than some drug doesn't *work*. If used carefully this could be useful.

Comment: Not sure, but I think that would qualify it as metatag